# can't login using sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, authentication

i am trying to create a login & logout functionality using session.

when i try to login it's not returning any errors but it's not redirecting  to root url or displaying a log out link from application.html.erb.

My configuration for session controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
end

def create
   user=User.authenticate(params[:email],params[:password])
 if user
    session[:user_id]=user.id
     redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Logged In'
  else
   flash.now.alert="authentication failed"

  end
end

 def destroy
   session[:user_id]=nil
   redirect_to 'log_in'
 end

end
```

sessions/new.html.erb:

```
<h4><strong>Log in</strong></h4>

<%= form_tag sessions_path do %>
   <div class="control-group">
    <%= label_tag :email %>
     <div class="controls">
       <%= text_field_tag :email,params[:email]%><br /><br />
  </div>
</div>

  <div class="control-group">
    <%= label_tag :password %>
     <div class="controls">
       <%= password_field_tag :password,class: 'form-control' %><br />    
    </div>
   </div>

   <div>
     <p class="button"><%= submit_tag %></p>
   </div>
 <%end%>
```

user model:

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessor :password
   before_save :encrypt_password

    has_many :posts
    has_many :profiles
    has_many :images

   validates_presence_of :password

    def self.authenticate(email,password)
       user=find_by_email(email)
    if user &&user.password_hash ==      BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password,user.password_salt)
  user
else
  nil
 end
end

def encrypt_password
  if password.present?
    self.password_salt=BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password_hash =  BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password,password_salt)
   end
 end

end

 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
    # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

   helper_method :current_user

   def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
 end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'log_in'=>'sessions#new', as: 'log_in'
  get 'sign_up'=>'users#new', as: 'sign_up'

   root to:'users#new'
   resources :users
   resources :profiles
   resources :posts
   resources :images
  resources :sessions
end
```

Comment: What log entries are being generated in your `development.log` when you try to login?

Comment: Started GET "/sessions/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-29 00:00:46 +0530
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (0.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 72ms (Views: 71.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Comment: That can't be it. You're looking for the login forms `POST` to `SessionsController#new` that happens after you have visited `Sessions#new`.

Comment: Started POST "/sessions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-29 15:56:15 +0530
Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"7YcWkeOsS5j2Ni+ZkjrQF+adG/KVnGYVUZLg0ozFh7N1kB4pFcSHy5sUszv7//E+7rWfDcRHPgtltiQU9Ipa6A==", "email"=>"karthik.mec1@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Save changes"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = 'karthik.mec1@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
  Rendered sessions/create.html.erb within layouts/application (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 166ms (Views: 80.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)

Comment: and i am getting sessions#create page with login link on top.upon click i am redirected to login page

Comment: Then in all likelyhood `User.authenticate` fails. Try logging both given and expected password hashes in it.

Comment: root is assigned to users#new. I'm pretty sure that the new action sets the session[:user_id] to nil.

Comment: @klausinho : in your scenario i should get at least  a logged in "notice".

Comment: @janfoeh :i suspected authentication failure might be a reason. i looked for solutions and couldn't find any. could you be more clear on your suggestion and won't i get a flash message saying authentication has failed.

Answer (score 0):

Guys found the solution.

In User.rb we have an authenticate method, which authenticates based on "USER" email address and password. user=find_by_email(email) should be 
    user=User.find_by_email(email).